# Recursion Python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def removedups(word):
  if len(word)<=1:
    return word
  else:
    if word[0]==word[1]:
      return removedups(word[1:])
    else:
      return word[0]+removedups(word[1:])

print(removedups('aabbcc'))
```

I dont get how the recursion works for this case. My knowledge so far is:

1) it skips the base test

2) goes to the recursion call and returns 'abbcc', and then it starts over again:

3) the if statement in recursion call is false so you disregard it

4) The else statement is where i get confused when it says `return word[0] +removedups(word[1:])`. Does it go the if statement and checks the word('bbcc')

Comment: Btw, that first `else` clause can be removed, and the second `if` can become one `elif`, and moved back an indentation with the last `else`. Proper syntax ;)

Comment: Actually both of the `else` can be removed. Concise code:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return word[0]+removedups(word[1:])
```

word[0]+removedups(word[1:]) is returned only when the execution of removedups(word[1:]) is complete.

removedups('bbcc') returns 'bc'

So removedups('abbcc') returns 'a' + 'bc' i.e. 'abc'

Comment: Hi! if u dont mind can you explain in a bit more detailed pls

Comment: `removedups('aabbcc')
 = removedups('abbcc') = 'a' + removedups('bbcc')
removedups('bbcc') = removedups('bcc') = 'b' + removedups('cc')
removedups('cc') = removedups('c') = 'c'`

Answer (score 1):

You get to that last `else` if the list has at least 2 elements and the first 2 aren't the same.  This means that the first element  is not a duplicate, and thus needs to appear in the result.  But there may be other duplicates in the rest of the list.  Thus, the answer is to add back that first element onto what you get by removing any duplicates from the rest of the list: `word[0]+removedups(word[1:])`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to visualize a recursion is by drawing a recursion tree.

```
 removedups("aabbcc") --> removedups("abbcc") --> "a" + removedups("bbcc") --> removedups("bcc") --> "b" + removedups("cc")  --> removeups("c") --> "c"
```

During traceback:

```
  removedups("cc") = removeups("c") = "c"
  => "b" + removedups("cc") = "bc"
  removedups("bbcc") = removedups("bcc") = "bc"
  => "a" + removedups("bbcc") = "abc"
  removedups("aabbcc") = removedups("abbcc") = "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

The last else condition and base case are responsible for producing `'abc'` result.Whereas `else:    if word[0]==word[1]:` is removing duplicate elements.

`removedups('aabbcc')  =>removedups('abbcc')`

`removedups('abbcc')  =>'a' + removedups('bbcc')`

```
'a' + removedups('bbcc')  =>'a'+ removedups('bcc')

'a' removedups('bcc') =>'ab' + removedups('cc')

'ab' + removedups('cc') => 'ab' + removedups('c')

'ab' + removedups('c') => 'abc'
```